# PHP: is there a way to execute a function/method when no method is called on an object?

Tags: php, class, object, magic-methods

I have an object that stores another subObject in it's data attribute. The subObject in the data attribute can be called vie a magic method like this:
`$object->subObject`. The subObject also has a data attribute in which it's value is stored. Currently when I do `$object->subObject` it automatically returns the value stored in the data attribute of the subObject. So basically the whole structure looks somewhat like this:

```
object [
    data => subObject [
        data => 'value'
    ]
]

$object->subObject //returns 'value'
```

I hope that this is understandable so far. Now I want to have the ability to execute `someFunc()` on the subObject: `$object->subObject->someFunc()`. That is generally not a problem. But I also want that, if I don't call a method on the subObject at all, the value of it's data attribute is returned ('value'). Is it possible to figure out within an object/a class if a method is called on it or not and act accordingly?

Comment: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-oop/php-__call/

Comment: @WiatroBosy I've tried __call. But when I don't call any method on my object at all, __call isn't executed. I need a sort of default method that is executed when I don't call a method on the object at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When you access a value, you get the same result regardless of what is going to be done with that value. It can't be different depending on whether you're going to call another method on it.

Remember that

```
$object->subObject->someFunc();
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
$temp = $object->subObject;
$temp->someFunc();
```

If the `$object->subObject` returned `'value'`, the first line would set `$temp = 'value'`, and then `$temp->someFunc()` wouldn't work.

Comment: I hoped that there would be some sort default method that is executed when I just call the object without a method like ```$object->subObject``` that returnes my 'value'. Like __call magic method. Problem with __call is, that it doesn't get executed when I don't call a method like ```someFunc()``` at all for example.

Comment: PHP doesn't have getters and setters. And even in languages that have them, they're called all the time, not just when you don't call another method on the result.